# Tomar filas donde a partir del campo1 solo contenga 1 único dato y no comparta dos

Tags: sql, oracle

Si tengo una tabla como esta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera solo coger aquellas filas donde a partir del campo1 solo contenga 1 único dato y no comparta dos. Es decir, si hago un `SELECT * FROM NAMETABLE WHERE CAMPO2 = 1;` me devolverá todas los resultados A, B y C ya que estos contienen "1", entonces en este caso solo quiero seleccionar la fila C que solo tiene 1.

Si realizo un "GROUP BY" `SELECT CAMPO1, CAMPO2, COUNT(*) FROM NAMETABLE GROUP BY CAMPO1, CAMPO2`, devolvería

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces si hago un `SELECT * FROM TABLA1 WHERE CAMPO2 = 1 AND CAMPO1 IN (SELECT CAMPO1 FROM TABLA1 GROUP BY CAMP2 HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)` me acaba filtrado en los casos B y C, pero el B contiene el 2. Y solo quiero el C ya que es el único que comparte solo 1 valor. Espero que se haya entendido el ejemplo.

Comment: Hola. Disculpa, pero no es claro el resultado que deseas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes expresar, en SQL, una consulta casi de manera idéntica a como lo has expresado en lenguaje coloquial.

```
select distinct Campo1
  from Tabla
 where Campo2 = 1
   and (select count(distinct campo2)
          from Tabla Aux
         where Aux.Campo1 = Tabla.Campo1
       ) = 1
```

La primera condición del `where` nos devuelve todo aquello que tenga el valor `1` en `campo2` y con la segunda condición nos aseguramos que, para el valor de `campo1` solamente haya un valor en `campo2`

Dejé el script para que puedas probarlo en [oracle live](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/ks7583bc89j9rmso8mo0roeve)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select campo1, count(*)
From(select campo1,campo2, 
Count(*) from Tabla
Group by campo1,campo2)temp
where campo2 = 1 and 
(select count(*) 
 from temp 
 group by campo1
) = 1
```

Lo que se hace aquí es en el from se hace una consulta agrupando por campo1 y campo2
Obteniéndose así un resumen ,y posteriormente a este resumen se le hace otro group by esta vez por campo1 , teniendo en cuenta que su total sea 1

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Pero no devuelve lo que quiero. Solo quiero aquellas filas donde el valor del campo 2 sea igual a "1". Entonces solo quiero que partiendo de valor del campo1 sea A, B o C únicamente filtre solo el que tienen valor "1".

Comment: mira a ver si esta nueva edicion te sirve

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza la clausula having

SELECT CAMPO1, CAMPO2, COUNT(*) as total
FROM NAMETABLE
GROUP BY CAMPO1, CAMPO2
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;

O bien

SELECT CAMPO1, CAMPO2, COUNT(*) as total
FROM NAMETABLE
GROUP BY CAMPO1, CAMPO2
HAVING total = 1;

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y procura explicar brevemente el funcionamiento de la consulta, además de darle formato al mismo. Lee [answer].